# Tobit regression in R, while looping regressions my data is not censored using censReg

Tags: r, loops, regression

hive mind!

I am looping regression analysis for multiple data sets (for each antibiotic and concentration).
Some of the data is censored at the lower limit of 3.912023. So I need to use censReg() instead of lm() in those cases.

Even though multiple subsets are including the lower limit the model output is the lm() for each regression.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

```
model.summary<- tibble()

for(j in unique(myData$antibiotic)){
        abx<- filter(myData, antibiotic == j)
        for(i in unique(abx$concentration)){
            if (min(abx$datapoints) == 3.912023){
                conc<-filter(abx, concentration == i)
                model<-censReg(x ~ y, data = conc, left = 3.912023) 
                model.coef<-coef(model)[2] 
                model.list<-c(j,i ,model.coef)
                model.summary<-bind_rows(model.summary, model.list)
} else {
                conc<-filter(abx, concentration == i)
                model<-lm(x ~ y, data = conc)
                model.coef<-coef(model)[2] 
                model.list<-c(j,i, model.coef)
                model.summary<-bind_rows(model.summary, model.list)
    }   

     }
}
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to the comments I fixed the problem. Using the numerical value (3.912023) of log(50) did not work for the `if-else loop` as well as a limit for `censReg`.  Using **log(datapoint)** instead solved the task.

```
model_summary <- tibble ()


for (j in unique(censored2$antibiotic)) {
        abxs <- filter(censored2, antibiotic == j)
        print(j)
        for (i in unique(abxs$MIC)) {
                print(i)
                MICs <- filter(abxs, MIC == i)
                if(min(MICs$logCFU) == log(50) ){
                         print("censored")
                        my_model <- censReg(logCFU ~ hours, data = MICs, left = log(50))
                        my_coef <- coef(my_model)[2]
                        my_list <- c(j,i,my_coef)
                        model_summary <- bind_rows(model_summary, my_list)
                 } else {
                         print("not censored")
                        my_model <- lm(logCFU ~ hours, data = MICs)
                        my_coef <- coef(my_model)[2]
                        my_list <- c(j,i,my_coef)
                        model_summary <- bind_rows(model_summary,my_list)
                 }
        }
}
```

Comment: I'd check if that if(min) statement evaluates to TRUE when you want it to. Checking equality on a real can be tricky because of the precision. It's possible it evaluates to FALSE every time and so runs lm() which is why you're not getting censoring

Comment: @NickCHK I followed your lead and calculated the regression for each subset, the problem seems to be my data. 
```censReg (Y ~ X, left = 3.91, right = Inf, data = myData)```

on myData
|antibiotic|conc|x|y| 
|B  |4  |0  |14.1|
|B  |4  |0.167|  4.61|
|B  |4  |0.5  |3.91|
|B  |4  |1  |3.91|
|B  |4  |2  |3.91|
|B  |4  |5  |3.91|

Results in "there are no censored observations"

I further investigated "rounding" errors and used [left = log(50)]

which results in another error
"Error in eigen(hess, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE) : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'"

Comment: use `dplyr::near()` or something like `abs(abx$datapoints - 3.912023) < 1e-7` (or some other numerical tolerance) to check for near-equality of real values.

Comment: @mikeck good idea, I checked for `near(log(50), 3.912023)` and it results in TRUE so it's not the numerical cut-off in the loop.

Comment: What I mean is that you can't use `==` reliably on real numbers. So you should replace `min(MICs$logCFU) == log(50)` in your if statement with `near(min(MICs$logCFU), log(50))`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you figure out in which round of the loop the problem occurs. Then, you can investigate the regression analysis in this selected round of the loop and provide a minimal example that illustrates the problem. (Sorry that I cannot post my comment as a "comment" because I have not yet "50 reputation".)

Comment: I think found part of the problem (thanks to @NickCHK & @mikeck): using **log values** interferes with min() and censReg().

the if-else statement works when I use the original Y instead of the numerical value of log(Y), same for the censoring `censReg(Y~X, left=Y)` instead of `censReg(log(Y)~X, left=log(Y)`

@Arne Henningsen, how would I transform the regression calculation then?

Comment: Do I correctly understand that there is left-censoring in *some* of the loops and if there is censoring, the lower limit is Y = 50 or, equivalently, log(Y) = log(50) = 3.912023? Does something like 'if( min( Y ) == 50 ) { res <- censreg( log(Y) ~ X, left = log(50) ) } else { res <- lm( log(Y) ~ X )}' work? If numerical inaccuracies create problems, you might try: 'Y <- Y / 50; if( min( Y ) == 1 ) { res <- censreg( log(Y) ~ X ) } else { res <- lm( log(Y) ~ X )}' (note: the default value of argument 'left' is 0 = log(1)).

Comment: Yes, the loop is for data where some observations are censored. The analysis is based on exp. bacterial growth. Therefore, I have to apply the log on the original data (Y) in order to calculate linear regression (cut off is log(50)).
Sorry for the labelling; log(Y) are the proper datapoints for `Y`.
As @mikeck estimated, I ran into problems using `==` on the real number of log(50) - `3.912023`. Once I changed it to `log(50)` , the loop and censReg worked for my case. To avoid further problems I followed his advice and included the near() `near(min(MICs$logCFU), log(50))`.